# chart library which can edit graph by dragging points?

Tags: charts, javascript

I'm looking for preferably javascript (but flash would do too) charting library which would be able to render time series as line chart and then allow to drag points in chart to change the underlying data.

I was said that Excel can do exactly the same thing, but I need it on web. No well-known charting library like Highcharts, amCharts, GoogleCharts or dygraphs cand apparently do that - I found some draggable graphs solutions like [WireIt](http://javascript.neyric.com/wireit/) or http://radokirov.com/js-graph-editor/ but these are nodes and edges types of graphs not really-usable for chart drawing.

Do you know any ready for use solution to this problem? I don't care whether it's opensource or commercial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Late response; I might help future visitors, though.

I'm looking for something similar. try: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html

Answer (score 0):

Some other options (hopefully helpful to future visitors):

- FusionCharts: https://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/visually-editable-charts/editable-line-chart
- Chart.js (plugin): https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragData