# Draggable points in Javascript chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I am searching for a javascript chart library. I want draggable points in a line chart, so the user can edit the values in the chart.

Is there any other than highcharts out there? I have found really cool ones for graphs(like [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)), but not for charts. Any thoughts/ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to search such libraries among the list of frameworks: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/javascript-graphs-and-charts-libraries Also a similar question was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920091/chart-library-which-can-edit-graph-by-dragging-points

Answer (score 2):

The RGraph Line chart is adjustable:

http://www.rgraph.net/docs/adjusting-line.html